# When will electromagnetic waves reflect? What are the criteria for reflections?

Tags: rf, wireless, electromagnetism, electromagnetic, optics

When an EM Wave comes to a boundary of two different media (i.e different electrical permitivity and magnetic permeability media), the things below could be seen:

- Reflections
- Refractions (Transmitted wave)
- Absorpiton
- Scattering (I am not sure)

I want to learn the criteria for the above events. For example, when do reflections occur? When does transmittance occur? Do they depend on the characteristic impedance or electrical permittivity differences of the media?

Comment: I don't know enough about it to give you a detailed answer but a hint I can give you is that EM waves are light and light is EM waves they behave the same/are the same and it is actually the same phenomena that make light get reflected or absorbed etc. it has to do with stuff like incident angle and propagation velocity in the different medii

Comment: @Vinzent, FYI, *media* is a plural noun. The singular is *medium*.

Comment: Right actually the double i was a typo but I'm not a native so S** happens ;P but thx anyway

Comment: A pedant writes: Thanks for removing criterias, but you're still using criteria incorrectly.  Criterion is singular, criteria is plural, so "What is the criteria" is incorrect. "What are the criteria" or "What is the criterion" is what should be written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea dependence is there.

At the interface between two mediums : ***1*** and ***2***, the amount of reflection of EM waves for perpendicular incidence, can be described by its reflection coefficient. 
$$\rho = \left(\frac{\eta_1 -\eta_2}{\eta_1 +\eta_2}\right)$$
where,
$$\eta_1 = \sqrt{\mu_1/\epsilon_1}$$
$$\eta_2 = \sqrt{\mu_2/\epsilon_2}$$
similarly the amount of transmission can be described corresponding transmission coefficient
$$\tau = 1+\rho $$

EDIT:

The coefficients are defined in terms of amplitudes of the incident, transmitted and reflected waves.

Comment: Dear @MITU RAJ, Thank you for reply.When an EM Wave passing through from Medium1 to Medium2 ; if characteristic impedance of two media is perfectly matched, there will not be reflections from boundary. However, If characteristic impedance of Medium1 is larger than Characteristic impedance of Medium2; an reflection will be seen at the boundary. In this case, reflection coefficient is positive. However, what will be mean that if reflection coefficient is negative ? ( In case of characteristic impedance of Medium2 is larger than Chracteristic impedance of Medium1 )

Comment: It just means that the polarity of the reflected wave will be opposite to the incident wave.

Comment: Dear @MITU RAJ, Thank you for reply. You mean that for example a square wave will reflects from boundary as turning upside down?  Another thing is that for example if reflection coefficient is 0.66, then this means that  66% of incident wave is reflected back from boundary and 34% of incident wave is transmitted to second medium ?

Comment: If transmission and reflection coefficients are defined in terms of amplitude, then its transmission coefficient will be 1+0.66 = 1.66 , not 0.34.

Comment: This answer is "very incomplete" (to be modest); only valid for perpendicular incidence. Reflectance (and so also transmittance) of EM radiation is, however,  **very** dependent on the angle of incidence and on polarization **and** there is a well known set of equations that describe the associated coefficients. Didn't find a trace of those well known facts in the answer. For more details see my answer.

Comment: @MITU RAJ: Of course transmission and reflection coefficients must add up to 1, i.e. \$\tau + \rho = 1\$; \$\tau=1+\rho\$ in the answer is wrong.

Comment: No. Your understanding is wrong. t = 1 + r  in terms of amplitude.....you can check here under "telecommunications" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_coefficient

Comment: @MITU RAJ: ...then please define the symbols you are using in your formula. Also expressions like "the amount of transmission" are anything but clear. Do you mean power or amplitude? (now I know that you mean amplitude, but it is not clear at all if you don't already know what you are trying to say)

Comment: Yea I meant amplitude. I will edit to add that clarity.

Answer (score 3):

> - Reflections
> - Refractions (Transmitted wave)
> - Absorption
> - scattering (I am not sure)

Generally, all four will happen at each interface between media.

Reflection occurs when the index of refraction is not perfectly matched between the two media.

Refraction will occur when the index of refraction is not perfectly matched and the angle of incidence is not exactly \$0^\circ\$ from normal. (And when there is not 100% reflection)

Scattering will occur when the interface between the media is not a perfectly flat plane.

Absorption mainly comes from propagation through any medium that is not perfectly lossless. It can also happen at an interface between media if there is some loss mechanism localized at the interface, such as a surface charge that isn't perfectly conductive.

Comment: Dear @The Photon, Thank you for reply. So, did you mean that for example, when an EM Waves passing through from Medium1 to Medium2 ; if refractive index of Medium1 is greater than refractive index of Medium2 ; then reflections will be seen. If refractive index of Medium1 is smaller than refractive index of Medium2, then reflections will not occur. Am I correct ?

Comment: No, if \$n_1 \ne n_2\$ there will be reflections, no matter which one is higher and which one is lower. There is one special case if  \$n_2 > n_1\$ and the polarization is correct and the angle of incidence is at the [Brewster angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brewster%27s_angle), then there will be no reflection. But there will be a reflection for any other incidence angle.

Comment: Dear @The Photon, got it. If refractive index of two media is not perfectly mathed, then reflections will be seen at the boundary. In fiber comm. a good reflection is targeted, however in Electrical comm. (i.e : in a transmission line) reflections will not desired. And reflections are tried to be minimized.

Comment: "Scattering will occur when the interface between the media is not a perfectly flat plane." It will occur more precisely when the surface has imperfections that are larger than the wavelength of the incident wave.

Answer (score 1):

There is a set of equations exactly describing what you are asking for: they are called the [Fresnel equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations).

**Reflection** and **transmission** are covered by the Fresnel equations.

**Scattering** is, however, not covered as it would depend on the roughness of the surface. So there can't be a generic formula for the scattering without quantifying the roughness (it also would be very dependent on the wavelength). 
The Fresnel equations assume a smooth surface (i.e. roughness much smaller than wavelength).

**Absorption** doesn't matter, as it doesn't happen at the surface but requires a  non-zero length of medium to be passed.

The Fresnel equations give coefficients of reflectance \$R\$ (i.e. ratio of reflected power to incident power) for EM radiation that is either polarized in the plane of incidence (p-polarized) or polarized perpendicular to the plane of incidence (s-polarized).

\$R_s = \lvert\frac{Z_2\cos\theta_i - Z_1\cos\theta_i}{Z_2\cos\theta_i + Z_1\cos\theta_i}\rvert^2\$

\$R_p = \lvert\frac{Z_2\cos\theta_t - Z_1\cos\theta_i}{Z_2\cos\theta_t + Z_1\cos\theta_i}\rvert^2\$

where
\$\theta_i =\$angle of incidence
\$\theta_t =\$angle of transmission

\$Z_k=\frac{\mu_k}{\epsilon_k}\$ and \$k\$ is an index 1 or 2 for the medium.

There are other versions of the formulars. E.g. under the assumption that \$\mu_1= \mu_2 = \mu_0\$ (permeability of vacuum) they can be rewritten as expressions of indices of refraction of both media.

(Note: since there are no non-linear effects involved you can compose any polarization into a linear combination of p- and s- polarized components).

Answer (score 0):

From what I've recently read, in trying to understand Efield shielding myself from the first principles, reflections occur when the material has polarizable atoms. The incoming energy gets (partially) stored by warping the electron orbits; warped orbits cause exciting behaviors in the material.

Look for the "wave coefficient" or "propagation coefficient" in the literature; this variable in its most general form will show various resonances (spectral lines) and show a general dependency with frequency, hence dispersion of pulses will occur.